# Intel GMA3150 on Samsung N150

Tags: intel-graphics, samsung

I'm new and proud owner of ubuntu on my Samsung N150. Everything seems to work fine, even the brightness which was an small issue in compare to Intel Media Graphics Accelerator (GMA 3150). I've read many tutorials through last days, but as I'm a complete beginner in Ubuntu system, I can't get to work it out.

In my system preferences the graphics card is unknown. I've installed some small .deb (`intel-gpu-tools_1.0.2+git20100830+c935c60-0ubuntu0sarvatt_i386.deb`). But it's not working for me.

Please, anyone help me! And thanks for your struggle to help me with this small problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Where did you get the .deb from?

Comment: Is there a way to test the performance of the intel 3150 against for example de 950?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that your drivers are actually working perfectly well.  The `Graphics` listing in `System Info` is wrong by default in Ubuntu 11.10.  It is based on the output of the `glxinfo` command, which we don't install by default.

It's highly likely that installing the `mesa-demos` package will correct the output of `System Info`.  This won't change your graphics performance or driver - it's highly likely that you're already using the correct drivers - it will just fix the reporting of your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the error you are getting while .deb package.

First tell what error is coming while running the package.
Then try to run it with gdebi(If you don't have gdebi installed, then install it via Ubuntu Software Center).
If gdebi is also not successful, then post the error of gdebi too.

If all fails, then open the terminal.
Go to the folder in which the .deb package is placed by suitable commands.
Then inside that directory, type

```
sudo dpkg -i [pkg name.deb]
```

And tell us if it helps you.

Comment: I stated it wrong. I have GDebi. I successfully installed this package, but the graphic is still unrecognized.