# GMA3150 on Samsung N100 (Atom N435) not working

Tags: intel-graphics, samsung

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop on Samsung n100 instead of MeeGo. And, unfortunately, when I opened System info, I saw that the graphics are undefined. I've installed the latest intel drivers (using tips from this site), but still nothing works. YouTube videos @360p and above aren'y smooth because of no hardware accel., which should have been provided by GMA3150.

How can I make the system recognize the graphics?

I have looked at the following questions:

- [Where can I download intel hd vga driver for my dell inspiron n5010?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84786/where-can-i-download-intel-hd-vga-driver-for-my-dell-inspiron-n5010)
- [Graphics driver for Intel 3150?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72605/graphics-driver-for-intel-3150)
- [Intel GMA3150 on Samsung N150](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67416/intel-gma3150-on-samsung-n150)

Comment: It would help if you could link to the questions you did try.

Comment: SOLVED!
'sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver'
'sudo apt-get update'
'sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel'
'sudo apt-get install mesa-demos'
Then reboot. Wait for update checker, update the packages, and then System Info showed Graphics as Intel IGD.

Comment: Post it as an answer so we can upvote it!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get install mesa-demos
```

Then reboot. Wait for update checker, update the packages, and then System Info showed Graphics as Intel IGD.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)